# SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name not showing the procedure content

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, linux, mysql-workbench

Hello I'm struggling with the Issue where i have to view the stored procedure content for that i have issue the command to get the name of the Procedure

```
mysql> SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
+-----+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Db  | Name                            | Type      | Definer   | Modified            | Created             | Security_type | Comment | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-----+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| vmp | ccontrol_table | PROCEDURE | user1@% | 2015-11-10 01:01:51 | 2015-11-10 01:01:51 | DEFINER       |         | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+-----+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)
```

It shows me the Procedure Exists with name **control_table**
To view the Procedure i have used **SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE control_table** it's display in this format not the **Content**

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE control_table;
+---------------------------------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Procedure                       | sql_mode | Create Procedure | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+---------------------------------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| control_table |          | NULL             | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+---------------------------------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

I Have executed this Using MySQL Client and mySQL Client Workbench, not able to view the procedure

There is no routine

```
mysql> SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES;
+--------------------+
| ROUTINE_DEFINITION |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

The MySQL Version

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| version                 | 5.1.73              |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64              |
| version_compile_os      | redhat-linux-gnu    |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.26 sec)


mysql> DESC control_table;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'control_table' doesn't exist
```

Comment: What do you get when you terminate with `\G` instead of `;` in `mysql`?

Comment: `SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE routine_name = 'control_table';`  What version of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames There is no routine_defintaion

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: Please run `DESC mysql.proc;`. There should be a column called 'BODY' which contains the source code of a stored procedure. Do you see such a column ???

Answer (score 1):

It just dawned on me. You must be using MySQL 8.0

I just heard about this headache not too long ago.

The [SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE for MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-procedure.html) does not show a `body` column anymore.

The design of [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/routines-table.html) is also different for MySQL 8.0.

Someone wrote about this 4 months ago (See [No more `mysql.proc` in MySQL 8.0](https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/)). This paradigm will take getting used to. Personally, I am not comfortable with it, but we need to just get used to it.

You also gotta wrap your head around [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/parameters-table.html), which itemizes each parameter passed to a stored procedure.

Just to skip all this other yucky stuff, [MySQL 8.0 FAQ says the following](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#faq-mysql-have-procedures-functions):

> Stored procedures are stored in the mysql.routines and
>   mysql.parameters tables, which are part of the data dictionary. You
>   cannot access these tables directly. Instead, query the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA ROUTINES and PARAMETERS tables. See Section 25.19,
>   “The INFORMATION_SCHEMA ROUTINES Table”, and Section 25.12, “The
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA PARAMETERS Table”.
>
> You can also use SHOW CREATE FUNCTION to obtain information about
>   stored functions, and SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE to obtain information
>   about stored procedures. See Section 13.7.6.9, “SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE
>   Syntax”.

I will leave it to you to reserch the rest of this.

Comment: Updated the Question